# Cinematographic camera manipulation techniques for a 2D adventure game

Tags: adventure-games

I'm coding a subsystem to manipulate camera for our 2D adventure game.

I plan to support panning and zooming. Also, perhaps, rotation (but current scenario does not call for that). We also support parallax scrolling, if that matters.

To better understand what means of expression my level-designer would need to design best experience for the player in cutscenes, I'm looking for a good documentation on relevant cinematographic camera manipulation techniques. (Yes, of course, I plan to have a discussion with my level-designers as well.)

Maybe there is a good basic guide for a camera manipulation in a 2d-animation movie or something like that — what techniques are there, and when to use what.

Or maybe there is some relevant document that is written from the game-development point of view?

Any advice welcome.

Comment: Questions asking for an overview of techniques or a discussion about said techniques are generally too broad to provide a single answer for.

Comment: Just properly interpolate the camera to a given set of waypoints. That should be a good enough cinematographic camera. For more control, try Catmull-Rom splines mixed with exponential interpolators.

Comment: Gustavo, I'm asking about higher-level techniques — i.e. "zoom on character face when he's talking".

Comment: Josh, this is very unfortunate. Also, I believe that an answer with  a digest of the links to the relevant works would do just perfectly.

Comment: Here is more or less what I mean: http://www.westga.edu/~mmcfar/Film%20Camera%20Shots.htm

Would like to see a little more sophisticated document though.

Comment: Here is exactly what I'm looking for — and more: http://floobynooby.blogspot.ru/2013/12/the-cinematography-of-incredibles-part-1.html